# iOS 10 Beta Updates

Tags: ios, iphone

My partner just took my old iPhone 6. I had this running the public beta. I have since wiped all data using the reset functionality. My question is... will it continue to update?

Comment: What iOS version do you have on the phone now?

Comment: Are you asking if beta updates are still enabled or if when iOS 10 is released, the normal update will happen?

Comment: Latest public beta but I am not signed into it any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for it to update to public beta software the phone needs to have a profile downloaded on the device which can be obtained from Apple's [beta site](https://beta.apple.com/profile) assuming you signed up for it then you could just log in with your Apple ID and download it which will then give you the updates for the beta software.